# Symbolic predicate logic for "for all elements in a set except this one..."

Tags: logic, elementary-set-theory

How would a statement beginning, "For all $x$ in set $S$ except $x=a$..." be translated into symbolic predicate logic? I'm somewhat of a purist in symbols and am less than satisfied with "$\forall x \in S$ except $x = a$..." or "$\forall x \in S$ where $x \ne a$...".

Comment: As the comment on one of the answers suggests, the question in the title is not the same as the question in the body. The title says "except one...", which may be any one, and need not be *a* in particular: it might be *b* or *c* or .... It is more complicated to express "all elements except exactly one" than it is to express "all except this particular one."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The exact correspondence in first order language is as follows:

$∀x((x∈S ∧ x≠a) → ⋯)$

It reads: for all $x$, if $x$ belongs to $S$ and $x$ is not $a$, then....

$x≠a$ is just a short form for $￢(x=a)$

Comment: This is good if we interpret "for all $x$ except $a$, $Q(x)$ holds" as meaning "for all $x$ except **possibly** $a$, $Q(x)$ holds." If we interpret "except $a$" as implying that $Q(a)$ fails, a different translation is needed.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Which translation do you suggest?

Comment: @AndréNicolas "Except possibly a" is modal logic I believe. The OP asked for first-order logic.

Comment: I don't modal. Example: "Everyone in this room except Alice is overweight." Your translation says that if $x$ is not Alice, then $x$ is overweight.  Logically speaking, it says nothing about Alice's weight. That *may* be what is intended by the sentence "Everyone  in this room except Alice is overweight." But probably not. To be more mathematical, "Every real number except $0$ has a multiplicative inverse." If by this sentence we mean in particular that $0$ *doesn't* have a multiplicative inverse, your translation does not do the job. If we mean to say nothing about $0$, it does.

Comment: @AndréNicolas you are right, my PARTIAL statement (it has dots "...") does not say anything about a, that is because the OP did not say anything about a. You seem to suggest that what goes for the others, does not go for a (that is: it is negated). But that it's not always so. Depends on the rest of the sentence (the dots). In the dots you fill what happens to a. For example: "Everyone in this room except Alice is overweight and diabetic, Alice is just overweight". In the dots you put: Ox ∧ Dx ∧ ￢Oa.

Comment: @AndréNicolas In the case of multiplicative inverse and 0 you complete the sentence with: Ix ∧ ￢I0,meaning that x has an inverse and 0 does not have an inverse.

Comment: @AndréNicolas In any case the first part of the sentence (the one I wrote) is correct, you just have to put what happens to a in the dotted part

Comment: Certainly one can embed any desired information within the $\dots$.  My comment had to do with the fact that the informal meaning of "all except $a$ have property $P$" probably includes that $a$ does not have property $P$.

Answer (score 13):

$$\forall x \in S\setminus \{a\}, \,\,\,\ldots$$

Answer (score -1):

I would use $(\exists a\in S)(\forall x\in S)(x\neq a \Leftrightarrow \cdots)$.  It's not a direct correspondence to the English, but not everything in symbolic logic is.

Comment: this is not the correct translation I am afraid. It does admit the existence or possibly many a. (it says there is at least one a such that...). While the English text only admits one element called a. Syntactically you are replacing a constant (a) with a bound variable (also called a in your formula). But a bound variable is a dummy variable, so you can call it anything, for example y. And then it loses its unique identity

Comment: @magma: I think jwodder was answering the question in the subject as opposed to the question in the text; the text mentions a specific $a$, but I also initially read the question as asking about 'for all but one (unknown) element of the set $S$' from its subject.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki : jwodder statement says: for all x in S except SOME....so it does not reflect neither the title nor the body of the question. Besides, the title says exactly the same thing as the body (except one means except only one)

Comment: I think this is a valid interpretation of the _title_ of the question.

Comment: More precisely, it is a valid interpretation of the title the question had when this answer was written (and still had when I wrote my comment). Then it said: "for all elements in a set except one..."